# Is it safe to enable Direct I/O for a loop device backed by a sparse file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, loop-device, sparse-files

I'd like to have a sparse file, and mount it as a filesystem. It'd be great if the performance overhead is negligible, but only if that doesn't come with a data-loss risk! Is it safe to mount the sparse file with a Direct I/O loop device?

On one hand, [this announcement on LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/654701/) looks to be encouraging users to enable Direct I/O on loop devices backed by files, which is awesome!

On the other hand, [ext4's wiki article regarding Direct I/O](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Clarifying_Direct_IO%27s_Semantics) states:

> ... what happens if an O_DIRECT write needs to allocate blocks; for example, because the write is extending the size the file, or the write system call is writing into a sparse file's "hole" where a block had not been previously allocated. Certain Linux implementations fall back to buffered I/O, such that the data goes through the page cache. The current implementation does wait until the I/O has been posted (although not necessarily with a barrier such that the data is guaranteed written to stable store by the storage device). However, Linux does not wait until the metadata associated with the block allocation has been committed to the file system; hence, if the system crashes after an allocating write completes, there is no guarantee the data will be accessible to an application after the system reboots...